# JSON serialization/deserialization beginArray/endArray in C#

Tags: java, c#, android, json, .net-core

Client which was wrote in Java(Android) send me Json which is pack in array [] so java client use methods beginArray and endArray. I have code on my server:

```
public static void SerializeToStream<T>(Stream stream, T obj)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
    ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

And I thought, if I send it like that:

```
SerializeToStream<dynamic>(client.GetStream(),'[' );
SerializeToStream<AuthenticationResult>(client.GetStream(), a);
```

will help, but not really. I have error on client:

> expected begin_object but was string/char/int/etc. at line 1 column 1 c#

What I do wrong? If I did the same what client did I started message with `[`. Maybe someone has the same problem and know solution?

Comment: What happens when you don't use beginArray and endArray ?\

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I cannot because I have no client code(I mena I cannot modify) :( I just can connect to it